# WkWebView won't loadHTMLstring

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9, wkwebview

I'm trying to show in a WkWebView an html page that I previously downloaded and stored in a String.

This is how I setup my WkWebView:

```
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.blankView.frame)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.loadHTMLString(tipShow.htmlString!, baseURL: nil)
    view.addSubview(webView)
```

The html string i'm trying to show is:

```
      <html> <style type="text/css"> * { -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; /*
  Disable selection/copy in UIWebView */
     }
   </style> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
 initial-scale=1">

<title>TITLE</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script> </head>

  <body>




<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div align=justify style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px">

        <font size="4.5" face="HelveticaNeue-Light"><br>

        <p>
THIS IS A TEST
   </p>
</div> </div>

</body></html>
```

When the WkWebView shows in my View it stands like this forever.

[image]

Someone can explain me why and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**SWIFT**

You might be making it a bit too complicated. This worked for me ...

First, import WebKit

Second, create an @IBOutlet under your class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
```

Third, place the following in your viewDidLoad():

```
let htmlString:String! = "\(YourString)"
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL))
```

Comment: I was missing the proper baseURL

Comment: Can anyone provide Objective C version of this ?

Answer (score 17):

I met the same problem as you! The key problem is in the project settings:

Check your **Xcode Project > Target > Capabilities > App Sandbox**.

Make sure you've CHECKED the NetWork ✅ Incoming & ✅ Outgoing connections.

See the SreenShot Below:

[image]

Comment: This is not iOS, is it?

Comment: Re shallow:This case is for OSX WKWebView, But i guess in iOS will be similar

Comment: that fixes it... I only needed outgoing, but why do I need to have that capability to load a string I generated in the app and load using loadHTMLString()...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit too late for that, but here's the requested Objective-C version:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;
[self.webView loadHTMLString:strTemplateHTML baseURL:[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleURL];
```