# How to load css and js file from CacheDirectory with WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, webkit, wkwebview

I want load html file (file:////Library/Cache/sample1_web/index.html) from cacheDirectory with css and js files in WKWebView. But, it's not load css and js files in WKWebView.

I load with method: loadHTMLString:baseURL

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample1_web.zip"];
NSString *destPath = [self getCachePath];

if ([SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:filePath toDestination:destPath]) {
    NSLog(@"SUCCESS unzip!");

    NSError *erno = nil;
    NSString *urlHTML = [[self getCachePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/sample1_web/index.html"];
    NSString *contentFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:urlHTML encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&erno];
    NSURL *urlBase = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[self getCachePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample1_web"]] bundleURL];

    NSLog(@"@%@", urlBase);
    NSLog(@"@%@", contentFile);
    if (erno == nil) {
        [_webView loadHTMLString:contentFile baseURL:urlBase];
    }else
        NSLog(@"%@", erno);

} else {
    NSLog(@"FAILED unzip...");
}

[self.view addSubview:_webView];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}    

- (NSString *)getCachePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

And, perfect load html but not with css and js. What is the problem? And I tried with UIWebView load this html and success load html with css and js.

And I check:

-https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61891/wkwebview-load-local-content-with-loadfileurl
-[WkWebView won't loadHTMLstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013812/wkwebview-wont-loadhtmlstring)

Comment: Try this API `func loadFileURL(_ URL: URL, 
allowingReadAccessTo readAccessURL: URL) -> WKNavigation?`

Give access to your base url.

Answer (score 0):

If your resources are zipped, and you only unzip them *in memory* (not on the file system) when loading the HTML, your JavaScript and CSS files remain zipped and the paths in your `<script src="js/script.js">` tags will not be valid because the `src` paths don't exist.

You need to unzip the whole directory so that all your resources are visible to each other.